When I log out, I get a blank page - Django 5
So when I want to log out the user it shows a white blank page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/
I'm using the shortcut way to redirect to next page in settings.py and I tested to logout with admin panel and it works fine.
settings.py
... 

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index' 

...

this is my urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('post.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls') ),
]

This is how I login:
login.html:
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h1> LOGIN FORM </h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-success">Log In</button>
</form>
</div>
<br>
{% endblock content %}

base.html:
...
<ul>
          <li><a class="active " href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="active " href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a class="active " href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a class="active " href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a></li>
           {% endif %}
        </ul>

...

and for log out all I did was the 'href="{% url 'logout' %}"' in base.html as far as I learned there is no code needed in views.py.
.what am I missing?

Support for logging out via GET requests in the django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView and django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login() was removed in Django 5.0. you need to use a POST request

See https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/deprecation-of-get-method-for-logoutview/25533/5 for how to implement this.

@16171413 how can this be done without using  tag?

You have to make certain changes into your file. To call index you have to define '/' into your settings.py file
settings.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('post.urls')),
]

post/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.logout, name="index")
]

post/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def logout(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


As mentioned in the comments, support for logging out via GET requests in the django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView and django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login() was removed in Django 5.0. You need to use a POST method. This fix was done to improve security. See https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/deprecation-of-get-method-for-logoutview/25533/5.
This is how to implement a POST method for logout:
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>

If you want to keep using a GET method, then you should downgrade your Django to < 5.0.
